# Best practice for making code portable for domains, subdomains or directores

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, subdirectory

I recently coded something where it wasn't known if the end code would reside in a subdomain (http://user.domain.com/) or in a subdomain (http://domain.com/user), and I was lost as to the best practice for these unknown scenarios. I could thinks of a couple:

1. Use absolute paths (/css/styles.css) and modrewrite if it ends up being /user
2. Have a settings file and declare a variable with the path (`<? php echo $domain . "/css/styles" ?>`)
3. Use relative paths (../css/styles.css).

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is any question about where something might be deployed, I would avoid absolute paths whenever possible, and if you must use them, make sure to construct them using the data in the `$_SERVER` superglobal. The value `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will contain the path and filename to the currently executing script, and you can then extract the path using something like:

```
$path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Likewise, the value `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will contain the current host, and from those two together you can build the path to wherever you are. If you're using HTTPS you may also need to check the protocol in `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`.

With that said, it is still best to use relative paths and a simple file and directory structure whenever possible, since it makes everything more portable and easier to read. If, as in your example, you find yourself doing a lot of `../css/styles.css` then you may want to reconsider how things are structured.

Answer (score 1):

Mix of 2 and 3.  Use paths relative to a set variable.